# Illustrator: how to turn artwork to outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

The first image is part of my current Illustrator artwork. How would I go about turning it into a thin outline, so that it looks like the second image except the lines need to be one pixel thick.

[image: enter image descdption here]

[image: enter image descripdtion here]

Comment: Give everything a 1px black stroke and no/white fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select all your artwork (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Go to the `Color` palette and set the `Fills` to *none* (pink arrow 1) and the `Strokes` to *black* (pink arrow 2)

  [image: color palette]
- Go to the `Stroke` palette and type `1 px` in the `Weight` field

  [image: stroke palette]
- If the resulting artwork has overlapping shapes, you need to selectively use a white fill and play with object ordering and/or pathfinder to adjust the result (eg. use white for shapes that need to be on top of other shapes and send them to the front using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or move these to a new layer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer unfortunately the original object used to build the artwork aren't perfect and overlap.  How can i solve this?   https://i.gyazo.com/1a1c0c99c228debf59acac25ae6e1675.png

Comment: I updated my answer above with another bullet that should address this. If you feel this answers your question, try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above, to the left of the bullets. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks